# correr loop atualizado com js retornando outro

Tags: javascript, array

bom o codigo é esse aqui de baixo onde:

```
<html>  
<head>
<style>
#main {
    border:#333;
    border-width:2px;
    border-style:solid;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">



var map =    Array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]);

var objectMap = Array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
var objectDict = Array("casa1.png","arvore.png");
var tileDict = Array("water.png","land.png","swamp.png");
var charDict = Array("mario.png");
var charImg = new Array();
var tileImg = new Array();
var objectImg = new Array();
var loaded = 0;
var loadTimer;
var tileH = 25;
var tileW = 50;
var ymouse;
var xmouse;
var mapX = 550;
var mapY = -100;
var playerX = 10;
var playerY = 10;
var newplayerX = 15;
var newplayerY = 10;
var jogadores;
var xpos;
var ypos;




var x;










function loadImg(){
    for(var i=0;i<tileDict.length;i++){
    tileImg[i] = new Image();
    tileImg[i].src = tileDict[i];
    tileImg[i].onload = function(){
        loaded++;
    }
}
for(var i=0;i<charDict.length;i++){
    charImg[i] = new Image();
    charImg[i].src = charDict[i];
    charImg[i].onload = function(){
        loaded++;
    }
}
for(var i=0;i<objectDict.length;i++){
    objectImg[i] = new Image();
    objectImg[i].src = objectDict[i];
    objectImg[i].onload = function(){
        loaded++;
    }
}


}





function loadAll(){
if(loaded == tileDict.length + charDict.length + objectDict.length){
    clearInterval(loadTimer);
    loadTimer = setInterval(gameUpdate,1000);
}
}


function gameUpdate(){
ctx.clearRect(0,0,350,230)
drawMap();
}


function mouseCheck(e){
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    ymouse=(2*(y-canvas.offsetTop-mapY)-x+canvas.offsetLeft+mapX)/2;
    xmouse=x+ymouse-mapX-25-canvas.offsetLeft
    ymouse=Math.round(ymouse/25);
    xmouse=Math.round(xmouse/25);
    document.title = "tileY:" + ymouse + " | tileX:" + xmouse;


document.getElementById("vy").innerHTML = newplayerX;
document.getElementById("vx").innerHTML = newplayerY;   



}



function drawMap(){

    for(i=0;i<map.length;i++){
            for(j=0;j<map[i].length;j++){
                var drawTile = map[i][j];
                var jogador = map[i][j];
                var drawObj = objectMap[i][j];
                var xpos = (i-j)*tileH + mapX;
                var ypos = (i+j)*tileH/2+ mapY;
                ctx.drawImage(tileImg[drawTile],xpos,ypos);
                if(drawObj){
                    ctx.drawImage(objectImg[drawObj-1],xpos,ypos-    (objectImg[drawObj-1].height/2));
            }









                if(i == xmouse && j == ymouse){
                                          ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 120, 0.7)';
                                          ctx.beginPath();
                                          ctx.moveTo(xpos, ypos+12.5);
                                          ctx.lineTo(xpos+25, ypos);
                                          ctx.lineTo(xpos+50, ypos+12.5);
                                          ctx.lineTo(xpos+25, ypos+25);
                                          ctx.fill();

                    }
            }




    }




};



function mouseClick(e)
{

var xpos = (newplayerX+newplayerY)*this.tileH/2 + mapX;
var ypos = (newplayerX+newplayerY)*this.tileH/2+ mapY;


ctx.drawImage(charImg[0],xpos,ypos);


newX = playerX; // local copies
newY = playerY;

if(xmouse > newX) newX++;
if(ymouse > newY) newY++;
if(xmouse < newX) newX--;
if(ymouse < newY) newY--;

if(objectMap[newX] && objectMap[newX][newY] !== 1 && map[newX] && map[newX][newY] !== undefined)
{
    playerX = newX;
    playerY = newY;
}




map[xmouse][ymouse]=2;




};





function init(){


canvas = document.getElementById('main')
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');  
loadImg();

loadTimer = setInterval(loadAll,100);

var Timer = setInterval(mouseClick,800);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseCheck, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseClick, false);





document.getElementById("send_string_array").value = map.join("],[");




};





</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="init();">
<p id="nickname"></p>
<canvas id="main" width="1024" height="550" style="margin-top:100px;     margin-left:100px;"></canvas

onload="initPage();"
    onunload="exitPage();"
    >
    <div id="y">posiçaox >> <span id="vy"></span></div>
    <div id="y">posiçaoy >> <span id="vx"></span></div>

  <p id="log"></p>
  <p id="data_recieved"></p>
  <body>



<form method="post" action="recebe.php" >
<input type="hidden" id="send_string_array" name="send_string_array" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form> 
</body>
<head>
```

ok até ai tudo bem na funçao mouseclick temos isso aqui:

```
 map[xmouse][ymouse]=2;
```

ele edita o array map onde estiver 0 e alguem clicar fica com valor 2 ou se estiver 1 e ele clica fica om valor 2, até aqui tudo funciona perfeitamente, mas veja esse código que esta dentro da funçao init:

```
document.getElementById("send_string_array").value = map.join("],[");
```

ele nao esta capturando o array map com as ediçoes, ele esta esta capturando o array que ainda nao foi editado quando se clica, porque isso esta acontecendo?

obs:
o codigo acima captura o array e envia para um arquivo php que deveria mostrar o codigo editado o php é esse codigo abaixo:

```
<?php

//transforma a string de itens separados em array
$array_produtos = explode("|", $_POST['send_string_array']);
//mostra o conteúdo do array
echo $_POST['send_string_array'];

?>
```

acho que é um erro simples de se resolver mas virei a noite e ainda nao achei o erro.

Answer (score 2):

A sua função `init` só executa uma vez, quando a página carrega.

Se você quer que o elemento `send_string_array` reflita o estado atual da array `map`, precisa atualizar o conteúdo desse elemento toda vez que `map` for alterada. O ideal é criar uma função pra isso:

```
function mapAtualizado() {
    document.getElementById("send_string_array").value = JSON.stringify(map);
    // nota: converter pra JSON é melhor que o join, resolve mais casos
}
```

E aí você chama essa função tanto no `init`, quanto no trecho que altera o `map`:

```
function mouseClick(e) {

    // seu código
    // ...

    map[xmouse][ymouse]=2;

    // Inserir isto:
    mapAtualizado();

};

function init(){
    canvas = document.getElementById('main')
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');  
    loadImg();

    loadTimer = setInterval(loadAll,100);

    var Timer = setInterval(mouseClick,800);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseCheck, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseClick, false);

    mapAtualizado();
};
```